# Fiware IoT Agent Json refused to POST to /v2/op/update

Tags: api, request, iot, fiware

I am interested in fiware IoT Agent JSON, and i tried to work things out.
I've mange to install the IoT Agent JSON using [this](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.IoT-Agent-JSON) tutorial.
The tutorial refers about IoT Actuator Connection and to check the connection we have to POST to {IoTAgentIP:Port}/v2/op/update.
When I post to this endpoint I get:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
   <pre>Cannot POST /v2/op/update</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

My Post Command Is:

```
curl -iX POST \
  http://localhost:4041/v2/op/update \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
    "actionType": "update",
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Alarm",
            "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Alarm:001",
            "ring" : {
                "type": "command",
                "value": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

And

```
curl -iX POST \
  http://localhost:4041/v2/op/update \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
    "actionType": "update",
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Bell",
            "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001",
            "ring" : {
                "type": "command",
                "value": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

My IoT agent version is:

```
{
    "libVersion": "2.12.0-next",
    "port": 4041,
    "baseRoot": "/",
    "version": "1.14.0-next"
}
```

Update - With latest Version of IoTA and orion I get in the IoTA log File the below:

```
time=2020-10-22T20:46:49.063Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | trans=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Creating initial entity in the Context Broker:
 {
    "url": "http://localhost:1026/v1/updateContext",
    "method": "POST",
    "json": {
        "contextElements": [
            {
                "type": "Bell",
                "isPattern": "false",
                "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Bell:001",
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "refStore",
                        "type": "Relationship",
                        "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ring_status",
                        "type": "commandStatus",
                        "value": "UNKNOWN"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ring_info",
                        "type": "commandResult",
                        "value": " "
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "TimeInstant",
                        "type": "ISO8601",
                        "value": " "
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "updateAction": "APPEND"
    },
    "headers": {
        "fiware-service": "openiot",
        "fiware-servicepath": "/",
        "fiware-correlator": "7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff"
    }
} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2020-10-22T20:46:49.063Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | trans=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=executeWithSecurity | comp=IoTAgent
time=2020-10-22T20:46:49.063Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | trans=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Looking for group params ["type"] with queryObj {"type":"Bell"} | comp=IoTAgent
time=2020-10-22T20:46:49.069Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | trans=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBGroupRegister | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Device group for fields [["type"]] not found: [{"type":"Bell"}] | comp=IoTAgent
time=2020-10-22T20:46:49.069Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | trans=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=error {"name":"DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND","message":"Couldn\t find device group for fields: [\"type\"] and values: {\"type\":\"Bell\"}","code":404} in get group device | comp=IoTAgent
time=2020-10-22T20:46:49.097Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | trans=7c9fba8d-9262-4f81-9b4e-f71ab57953ff | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DeviceService | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Initial entity created successfully. | comp=IoTAgent
```

Comment: I upgrade my IoT Agent version and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Ensure that all images are latest by running `./services create` then re-run the commands as shown [in Postman](https://fiware.postman.co/collections/513743-04447599-7ac9-49f8-943d-4012147d50de?version=latest&workspace=56ef8b2e-ab05-408c-bbe9-7714cfe08cf6). If you run the `curl` commands with `-iX` you will get more information from the responses.

Comment: The `Cannot POST /v2/op/update` response can **only** be generated by the IoT Agent and can **only** occur if the port is correct and the path is incorrect, this would suggest that the `curl` statement was sent with a typo in it.

Comment: If you have further problems, please paste the full requests and responses using `curl -iX` to help diagnose problems further.

Comment: Great! I will investigate it and keep you updated

Comment: Hello, Do you have any combination of versions that you are using at the moment?  Can I use Orion version 2.2.0 via rpm install and I have recent IoT agent json v1.14 or 1.15?

Comment: I will update you with logs result when is possible

Comment: Tested Compatible version can be found in the [FIWARE Release Catalogue](https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue/releases). The latest Orion is 2.4.2 so you'll be missing some development and bug fixes. Since the components follow SemVer you  should be OK since the major version number hasn't changed.

Comment: I have the latest versions installed now and I got DEVICE_GROUP_NOT_FOUND in the log file. I've update my question

Comment: https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/issues/320

Comment: So, Can I add any args like (IOTA_DEFAULT_RESOURCE= ) or any other arg when my IoTAgent is running from stable source in a CentOS VM from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to make it to work with one service group (/iot/d). So Post requests to append a sensor goes from /iot/d service group.
I use docker images (compiled with docker compose, like the example).
I also have modified in docker file the IOTA_DEFAULT_RESOURCE just in case to be:
`IOTA_DEFAULT_RESOURCE=`
I've used the latest IoT Agent JSON 1.15.0  and the previous Version 2.4.0 of Orion.